# Get location/address of Amazon Echo device

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, alexa-skills-kit

I am making an Alexa skill which needs to send the location of the Echo being used to an API within my Lambda function.

https://www.amazon.com/gp/help/customer/display.html?nodeId=201601980 says we can access many details about the Echo, such as Device Location, but in my skill, I don't see this is available in the session:

```
exports.handler = function (event, context) {
   try {
       console.log("event.session: " + event.session);
```

How can I get this data?

The point is, while we have the address of the user coming from my App API, they may have set an address where they're not currently at (aka, they've placed an order from an Echo that's not the same as their address).

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get location from Alexa Skills Kit (ASK)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36986139/get-location-from-alexa-skills-kit-ask)

Answer (score 2):

Access to the profile information doesn't appear to be available. If the account is linked, the only option I see is to route them back to your web site to provide information necessary to complete the order.

Answer (score 0):

You can now get the address of the device, as specified in the customer’s device settings.

This is new as of 2017-04-05.  See [Amazon's blog post](https://developer.amazon.com/blogs/alexa/post/75db99e4-dc77-42d1-89d1-aa8b41301324/build-more-engaging-skills-with-device-address-api-and-gain-insights-with-the-new-metrics-dashboard) about their new [Device Address API](https://developer.amazon.com/public/solutions/alexa/alexa-skills-kit/docs/device-address-api).