# How to get the location of an Amazon Echo from an Alexa Skill

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit

I know that Amazon does not directly provide developers with a way to get the location of the user's echo, but I was wondering if there was a way around this. I'm writing the skills in node, so I have run into node packages like geoip, but when I upload the skill to aws lambda, I get an error that says something along the lines of the ELF headers are not correct. Any assistance would be much appreciated!

Comment: ELF headers seems to be a problem with the binary that you have uploaded to the Lambda function where Alexa is running as backend. Which geoip package are you using?

Comment: I didn't use geoip, but looking at what it is I got the idea that you have to pass ip address to geoip for it to detect location. I don't know a way to pass ip in the intent to your skill otherwise than ask user to say it, which seems ridiculous. So I don't think geoip can be of any help here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get location/address of Amazon Echo device](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38001615/get-location-address-of-amazon-echo-device)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get location from Alexa Skills Kit (ASK)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36986139/get-location-from-alexa-skills-kit-ask)

Answer (score 1):

You can now get the address of the device, as specified in the customer’s device settings.

This is new as of 2017-04-05.  See [Amazon's blog post](https://developer.amazon.com/blogs/alexa/post/75db99e4-dc77-42d1-89d1-aa8b41301324/build-more-engaging-skills-with-device-address-api-and-gain-insights-with-the-new-metrics-dashboard) about their new [Device Address API](https://developer.amazon.com/public/solutions/alexa/alexa-skills-kit/docs/device-address-api).

I'm not sure exactly what you are after, but this new API can give two different levels of address (Country and postal code only, or full address).  To get their location you would need to use another API to translate the address into location coordinates.  This is called a Geocoding API and Google Maps API includes this capability (for example).